# After wake up the authentication dialog freezes

Tags: server, suspend, mysql

Yesterday I updated my computer from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. Normally the mysql server on my computer was not starting on boot. I was launching it myself when I need it. With yesterday's update, the server started to launch at boot. This feature is good for me, but there is a problem.
If I put the computer to sleep and turn it on again, it started to request authentication to start the mysql service. The window opened for authentication is not closing in any way and is not accepting the password. It is fixed in the upper left corner and it isn't moving. To close this window, I need to log out and log in again or restart the computer.
I tried shutting down the mysql service with the `systemctl stop mysql.service` command, but it didn't work. What can I do? Thanks...
Notice: forgive me for my English if I did mistakes, I'm an English student :)

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl stop mysql.service
```

simply stops the process but will start again after reboot. You need to issue

```
systemctl disable mysql.service
```

to ensure it will not start during boot time.

If you are bold, you could install a timer service that will start youre service after a given time. Lookup the systemd documentation for systemd timers

Comment: Thanks. I found a bug record on the subject. According to what is written on the page, when typing "r" in the window opened with ALT + F2, the gnome shell is reloaded and the window which does not close disappears. I hope a solution to this bug can be found.
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1824874](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1824874)